# Boost library, using std::wstring as filename with boost::property_tree::read_xml

Tags: c++, xml, boost, wstring, widestring

I recently started using `std::wstring` instead of `std::string` to avoid weird results with non-ASCII characters, and I didn't find a way to read an XML file where the path is of type `std::wstring` using the boost library.

I'm using the [boost](http://www.boost.org/) library quiet a lot nowadays.

I use the `boost::property_tree::read_xml` function with `boost::property_tree::wptree` instead of the usual ptree struct. But sadly I cannot feed a `std::wstring` as the first parameter to read_xml which makes it all harder.

My question is, are  there any work around for reading a XML file where the path is storted as a `std::wstring`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the Boost Iostreams `file_descriptor_sink` device which supports `wpath` from Boost Filesystem:

```
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/file_descriptor.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace pt = boost::property_tree;
namespace io = boost::iostreams;
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

int main()
{
    fs::wpath const fname = L"test.xml";
    io::file_descriptor_source fs(fname);
    io::stream<io::file_descriptor_source> fsstream(fs);

    pt::ptree xml;
    pt::read_xml(fsstream, xml);

    for (auto const& node : xml.get_child("root"))
        std::cout << node.first << ": " << node.second.get_value<std::string>() << "\n";
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75d8f6d5952fc908)** where it uses the input file:

```xml
<root>
    <child nodetype="element" with="attributes">monkey show</child>
    <child nodetype="element">monkey do</child>
</root>
```

and prints:

```
child: monkey show
child: monkey do
```

Comment: Does this work if my filename or path contains non ascii characters?

Comment: @ashishg I haven't tested this, but I think `boost::filesystem::path::codecvt()` performs the relevant conversion so: yes

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7007dd21b1c12f14 I tried modifying your example to include a non ascii and it errored out.

Comment: @ashishg works for me. Anyhoops, imbueing a specific locale *[does the job on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/393e7bd6069b3ce5)

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution which was rather simple, all I did was use the `std::wifstream` as the first parameter of the `boost::property_tree::read_xml` method.

Basically three lines of code:

```
boost::property_tree::wptree pt;
std::wifstream f(L"C:/äöå/file.xml");
boost::property_tree::read_xml(f, pt);
```

Comment: That's not portable: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream - this is also the reason that `boost::iostreams::file_source` **[doesn't support wide string filenames](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/3088)** (because it relies on `std::fstream`) - that boost issue #3088 is marked "WontFix" for this very reason.

Comment: @sehe Okay, but it does work on Microsoft windows? Because my application is not (yet) made cross-platform. Anyway thank you for the information and the answer.

Comment: Cheers. I assume it just works with MSVC's standard library implementation. (It will still not work with MingW, GCC, Clang or Intel C++ compiler on windows). It's not the first thing  that MSVC has non-standard. In general, wstring is rarely used outside Windows, because only on MSVC does wstring have 16-bit char types and that happens to coincide with the Windows "preferred" character encoding of UTF16

Comment: @sehe I see, well would there be any benefit to use your method if developing on windows and in Visual Studio? Vcredist is going to be installed on all the computers running my program.

Comment: I bet no. You can use the MSVC extension if that's all you wish to support. ([docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zek0beca.aspx))

Comment: @sehe Okay, but the example was nice, though. I can't use wptree using the boost stream, but that is not necessary unless the XML file contains non-ASCII characters?